# Mariadb server error

Tags: 18.04, systemd, mariadb

I'm trying to rationalize my mariadb installation. (I've tried uninstall and reinstalling and may need to dig deeper to reset it correctly)

When I run 'systemctl status mariadb' the follow is displayed.

```
systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.1.38 database server..
[Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 22
[ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
[ERROR] Aborting
systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Any pointers for how to solve this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try symlinking the files:

```
ln -s usr/share/english/errmsg.sys /usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys
```